# Use drawer indicator as back button

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I'm using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/) library to implement a basic material drawer in my app.

I wasted more than two days trying to figure out how to transform the menu toggle button (burger) to a back button, like Gmail app when you open an email.

In Gmail app when you open an email the menu icon is animated into a back arrow but the menu drawer remains still available.

I've tried to use `ValueAnimator` to animate the icon as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577437/824963). 
I've setted an onAnimationEnd listener to replace the menu icon with a working back button:

```
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

After doing that the menu drawer slide position get unlinked from the menu drawer icon animation, and when i try to restore the menu drawer button and animate it backwards it gets stuck:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

Actually a similar question has been already asked, and has been marked has duplicated when it is not: [Navigation Drawer with Burger to back arrow animation on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451722/navigation-drawer-with-burger-to-back-arrow-animation-on-lollipop)

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are using this library when the Android support libraries now support this? https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: because i didn't found anything mentioning the new menudrawer in the android documentation or example projects.
Anyway, in this cheesesquare sample when you select a cheese it starts a new activity, and the menu drawer is not accessible anymore

Comment: Well, I know for a fact that the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` works with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library on the Cheesesquare project