# No Hamburger to Arrow animation or icon showing on Drawer

Tags: android, xamarin-studio, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

So I watched this youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TahxgjZTpSA&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=49) tutorial and used his sample code (sample 50: http://cforbeginners.com/XamarinProjects.html) found in his website. I ran the sample, the Hamburger to Arrow animation appeared but when I tried to implement it on my solution project, no animation or icons.

I even went as far for testing; I created a new solution and literally copy the sample files unto the new solution and same results, no animation or icons. So at this point, I'm thinking is something internally that is causing the problem of no Hamburger to Arrow animation or icons.

I tried this solution and none of them work:

[ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState Doesn't show the hamburger icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285014/actionbardrawertoggle-syncstate-doesnt-show-the-hamburger-icon)

[Appcompatv7 - v21 Navigation drawer not showing hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon)

[Navigation Drawer with Burger to back arrow animation on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451722/navigation-drawer-with-burger-to-back-arrow-animation-on-lollipop)

Files from sample:

MainActivity:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "test.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, Theme="@style/MyTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity
    {
        private SupportToolbar mToolbar;
        private MyActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mLeftDrawer;
        private ListView mRightDrawer;
        private ArrayAdapter mLeftAdapter;
        private ArrayAdapter mRightAdapter;
        private List<string> mLeftDataSet;
        private List<string> mRightDataSet;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            mToolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);
            mRightDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.right_drawer);

            mLeftDrawer.Tag = 0;
            mRightDrawer.Tag = 1;

            SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

            mLeftDataSet = new List<string>();
            mLeftDataSet.Add ("Left Item 1");
            mLeftDataSet.Add ("Left Item 2");
            mLeftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mLeftDataSet);
            mLeftDrawer.Adapter = mLeftAdapter;

            mRightDataSet = new List<string>();
            mRightDataSet.Add ("Right Item 1");
            mRightDataSet.Add ("Right Item 2");
            mRightAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mRightDataSet);
            mRightDrawer.Adapter = mRightAdapter;

            mDrawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                           //Host Activity
                mDrawerLayout,                  //DrawerLayout
                Resource.String.openDrawer,     //Opened Message
                Resource.String.closeDrawer     //Closed Message
            );

            mDrawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.SyncState();

            if (bundle != null)
            {
                if (bundle.GetString("DrawerState") == "Opened")
                {
                    SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.openDrawer);
                }

                else
                {
                    SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.closeDrawer);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                //This is the first the time the activity is ran
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.closeDrawer);
            }
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
        {       
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {

            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                //The hamburger icon was clicked which means the drawer toggle will handle the event
                //all we need to do is ensure the right drawer is closed so the don't overlap
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer (mRightDrawer);
                mDrawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
                return true;

            case Resource.Id.action_refresh:
                //Refresh
                return true;

            case Resource.Id.action_help:
                if (mDrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(mRightDrawer))
                {
                    //Right Drawer is already open, close it
                    mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer(mRightDrawer);
                }

                else
                {
                    //Right Drawer is closed, open it and just in case close left drawer
                    mDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer (mRightDrawer);
                    mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer (mLeftDrawer);
                }

                return true;

            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
            }
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.action_menu, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
        }

        protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
        {
            if (mDrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen((int)GravityFlags.Left))
            {
                outState.PutString("DrawerState", "Opened");
            }

            else
            {
                outState.PutString("DrawerState", "Closed");
            }

            base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
        }

        protected override void OnPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnPostCreate (savedInstanceState);
            mDrawerToggle.SyncState();
        }

        public override void OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);
            mDrawerToggle.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

MyActionBarDrawerToggle:

```
using System;
using SupportActionBarDrawerToggle = Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;

namespace test.Droid
{
    public class MyActionBarDrawerToggle : SupportActionBarDrawerToggle
    {
        private ActionBarActivity mHostActivity;
        private int mOpenedResource;
        private int mClosedResource;

        public MyActionBarDrawerToggle (ActionBarActivity host, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openedResource, int closedResource) 
            : base(host, drawerLayout, openedResource, closedResource)
        {
            mHostActivity = host;
            mOpenedResource = openedResource;
            mClosedResource = closedResource;
        }

        public override void OnDrawerOpened (Android.Views.View drawerView)
        {   
            int drawerType = (int)drawerView.Tag;

            if (drawerType == 0)
            {
                base.OnDrawerOpened (drawerView);
                mHostActivity.SupportActionBar.SetTitle(mOpenedResource);
            }
        }

        public override void OnDrawerClosed (Android.Views.View drawerView)
        {
            int drawerType = (int)drawerView.Tag;

            if (drawerType == 0)
            {
                base.OnDrawerClosed (drawerView);
                mHostActivity.SupportActionBar.SetTitle(mClosedResource);
            }               
        }

        public override void OnDrawerSlide (Android.Views.View drawerView, float slideOffset)
        {
            int drawerType = (int)drawerView.Tag;

            if (drawerType == 0)
            {
                base.OnDrawerSlide (drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">#F5F5F5</item>
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The Main Content View -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Support V7 Action Bar Drawer Toggle"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2FD" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#E2E2E2"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#9E9E9E" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        myapp:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:title="Help"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the call to `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` on the `ActionBar`.

```
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you that work. The sample solution didn't include that statement and it still showed the animation. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: Gimme a minute. I'll take a look at the example code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I'm not actually familiar with Xamarin. I just know the analogous methods from the Java SDK. If I figure it out, I'll let ya know.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry about it.